# Anyone else annoyed by this advertisement?

Tags: discussion, advertising

There's one advertisement that frequently appears in the right margin of Stack Overflow pages, that I find annoying and distracting.  Does anyone else feel the same way?

> [image: Picture of ad. Description follows.]

The advertisement in question is for a Microsoft Developer Camp.  It has a man with his arms folded.  To the left of the man, there is a large cloud with a huge blue erect penis, and a love heart above the penis.

Have I misunderstood this advertisement?  Just what is it trying to tell me?

If I want to see cartoon pornography, I know how to find it.  Having it thrust at me on Stack Overflow is frankly a little disturbing.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: Come on @Mysticial, you MUST have seen the ad I'm describing.  It comes up very often (no pun intended) for me.

Comment: Haven't seen it either. Maybe SO determined your're into MS products and/or huge blue erect penises?

Comment: With that info, could it be an ad for [this event](http://events.msfthcp.com/?eventID=AP-Azure-IPVNT-FY15-04Apr-NZ%20Azure%20Day&ls=Email)? Microsoft + Cloud + Blue Penis totally sounds like Azure to me.

Comment: Hopefully.  I'll be quite pleased if it stops appearing after next Wednesday.

Comment: Were any lulz involved in your motivation for asking this question?

Comment: @LynelHudson  I'm not quite sure what you mean by lulz, but I find this ad extremely annoying and mildly offensive.  I would prefer not to see it.  I don't know how else to complain about an ad, than to raise it here on meta.

Comment: Never seen it. Adblock ftw.

Comment: That's not a penis. That's a stylised hand.

Comment: "Paging Doctor Freud..."

Comment: No way is that a hand.

Comment: Compare with the [previously linked ad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ZR4.jpg), that has the exact same hand design.  It's a hand.

Comment: @Retsam unless the electronic devices are holding coffee with their penises, that is.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question then.  If nobody else sees an erect penis in that graphic, then I suppose I have nothing to complain about.  But seriously?  Everyone thinks it's a hand?

Comment: I do admit the heart is suggestive, though

Comment: Let's just say that if I ever go to a Microsoft Developer Camp, I'll be keeping a very wary eye on any amorous-looking clouds.

Comment: Damn clouds! Think they are above everything. Including sexual harassment laws.

Comment: That's clearly a hand, what is wrong with you people? (or is it still April 1st in some magical timezone I am not aware of?)

Comment: My question was very serious.  I'd like to be able to use Stack Overflow at work. And I'd prefer not to have to explain to my boss why I'm visiting a web site with an image of a semi-pornographic well-endowed cloud.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ notsureifserious.jpeg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536110/ui-design-and-cultural-sensitivity-awareness

Comment: If that is a hand/arm sticking out of the cloud, why is there only one?

Comment: But if it was...um...'not a hand', then that makes the "don't fight" text really, REALLY bad.

Comment: Why do you keep editing the image out of the question so people have to visit an external page to see what you are moaning about?

Comment: Well, the whole point of my post is that I'd rather NOT have to look at this image.  And I'd rather NOT have the image immortalised, once Microsoft stop paying for Stack Overflow to show this ad.  As I explained last time someone edited the actual image into the question.  @MartinSmith

Comment: The image is an integral part of your question. It is not possible to answer it without seeing it. Not having it in the question so you personally don't have to see it inconveniences everyone else.

Comment: I guess when I posted, I assumed that everyone had seen this image.  I didn't know that this ad was only being shown to a limited group.  I still don't know what's special about me, that Stack Overflow thinks I might be interested in seeing the penis ad.  I really don't want to have the image on this page.

Comment: @David Wallace I believe that your avatar is inappropriate.  It's a picture of a penis

Comment: Dangit. Now I can't unsee that.

Comment: Could y'all maybe compromise with a tasteful blurring of the image instead of continually adding and removing it?

Comment: I firmly believe that ad blockers are some of the greatest pieces of software to have ever been written.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Fret not, @DavidWallace! There is a feature on all leaderboard and sidebar ad units that allows you to downvote an ad. You can provide one of five reasons (uninteresting, misleading, offensive, repetitive, other), and upon doing so, you will not be served that ad again-- unless you clear your cookies or browse from another platform.

[image: downvote-meh-20150408]

All you have to do is hover over an ad that you find objectionable and click the downvote button. Easy, right?

Remember: we only want you to see ads that are relevant to you. If you don't like what you're seeing, this should help.

Answer (score 29):

You're certainly not the first to discover logos that have [unintentional, hidden meanings](http://www.businessinsider.com/15-worst-corporate-logo-fails-2012-1?op=1).

If you click through to the article I linked, you'll notice quite a few gems.  Be forewarned that some are jaw-droppingly bad.

The only two of the fifteen that are safely linkable here are:

***London 2012 Olympics***

> [image: London 2012 Olympic logo]

and the ***Sinister Sherwin Williams***

> [image: 1906 Sherwin Williams logo]

What's worth pointing out in cases like this is that the innuendo likely wasn't intended.  All but one of those logos were for legitimate corporations whose brand image would have been significantly tarnished by an intentionally offensive logo.

---

So to answer your question:

> Anyone else annoyed by this advertisement?

I'm not sure that I'd chose "annoyed" as my feeling.  It's certainly off-putting though.  And it's clear that the advertisement is not having the intended effect that it's supposed to.

A more constructive approach would have been to click-through on the ad and contact the advertiser directly to let them know of your concerns.  Likewise, you could have directly contacted SE and let them know of your concerns.  SE will have direct contact information for the advertiser and can reach out to them as well.

Another constructive step would have been to phrase your meta question a bit more constructively.  But a meta question likely wouldn't get as quick of a response as contacting the advertiser or SE directly.

Unintentional gaffes like this happen on a semi-regular basis.  The important thing to do is not get overly upset about them, and politely point out the mistake to those who can actually do something about it.

Comment: Maybe its just me but that 2012 Olympics logo reminded me of a couple of generic SO avatar icons that new users get.

Comment: If a kids exchange site ever gets proposed, I am going to be strongly opposed to the subdomain _kidsexchange_ now

Comment: "A more constructive approach would have been to click-through on the ad..." No. Not if the advertiser pays on a per-click basis. That's doing nothing more than rewarding the publisher (in this case, Stack Exchange) for showing the ad in the first place.

Comment: @CarrieKendall something like *kidees*?