# Should questions destroyed as being offensive be used as review audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So, I was reviewing a question, and it totally seemed valid, but there was a picture at the start of the post, and, thinking it was related to the post, opened it, and was shocked to find that it was a picture of a penis. Once I flagged it, it informed me that this was a review audit, and I had passed.

Why does this highly inappropriate post show up as a review audit? I see all sorts of spam posts show up as audit reviews, and I can easily flag those, but is there not a filtering process as to which posts go into the review audit "queue"?

I can give the link to the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13461723) if that's necessary for context, but since this is a deleted question, I'm unsure if anyone but me can see the deleted posts.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem here.  There was an awful post, you said it was awful, and the system knew it was awful.  Good job, well done.  Go on to the next review.

Comment: @yellowantphil Well, the *point* of reviewing is specifically to be sorting through the worst of the content on the site...so they're going to be doing just that on the non-audit posts anyway.  If they're unwilling to look at the trash, they shouldn't sign up to be a trash collector.

Comment: Part of the job of reviewing is reviewing offensive material. If the idea here is that the audits *should* present offensive material but somehow not present material that is *too offensive*, I'd say this is a fool's errand. There's no telling what people find *too* offensive. Sure, posting an image of a penis is rude but it ranks pretty low in terms of offensiveness, in *my view*. I'd find a racist or sexist post more offensive. There's no way to filter the audits to get some sort of middle-of-the-road level of offensiveness that won't still be too much for some.

Comment: What's ... what's behind that link?  The image link on the review question...

Comment: I feel this is in the same spirit as [Blacklist the use of common link shorteners in posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts) and would be a good feature request.

Comment: are you sure that this picture was not a [Microsoft Developer Camp advertisement discussed here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289255/839601)?

Answer (score 50):

This is an interesting question. Generally, the thinking is that content flagged as spam or rude / offensive and deleted makes for pretty good audit material, because spam and blatantly offensive content should not be approved by reviewers under any circumstances. That's why validated spam and offensive flags on posts make them audit cases.

However, should reviewers be subjected to offensive material just to verify they're reviewing correctly? As moderators, we know that we're going to come across some pretty terrible stuff as part of what we do, but normal users shouldn't have to be exposed to that. There's a reason that validated offensive flags hide the content of posts, even after deletion.

I'm thinking that maybe validated offensive flags should not be used for audit cases. I don't think it would have a huge impact on the total number of audit cases, because truly offensive material is pretty rare, and is far less common than spam or just plain nonsense.

As a side note: the context for the specific review you saw there was that a troll was personally targeting meagar with a series of accounts posting some pretty nasty stuff. They also were attacking them offsite, at the same time that at least one other user was harassing meagar, which is what led to [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283725/make-moderator-messages-anonymous). In case you wanted to know.

Comment: Probably the links on those posts should be replaced with mildly offensive ones or better still with spam. If you're taking the time to look at the link and identify it as inappropriate for the site you should IMHO pass the audit regardless of how offended you were while doing so.

Comment: Perhaps from a perspective of protecting the brand it is also not really a great idea to keep these kind of audits in. I mean it only takes one smart kid seeing such a thing in review and one angry parent taking it to the media to smear the name of the site we love. Even if the chance is very small, it just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think we need validated offensive posts as audits. There is plenty of spam that makes for good audits to go around.

Many people are reviewing at work, and in any given review queue, the possibility of coming across blatantly offensive posts is relatively minor, due to the fact that these often don't outlive a minute on this site.

I think it would be prudent to stop using validated offensive flags as audits and instead sticking to spam. There is no need to subject people to content that could get them in trouble at work just for audit purposes.

Sure, during review you might come across some seriously messed up stuff and thats expected and normal, but there is no need to inflict this on reviewers when we don't need to, and a fix to this is very trivial without compromising any aspect of the purpose of audits.

Comment: Yeah, I have well over 10k reviews network-wide, and I've never run across anything nearly as blatant as what's described, so testing reviewers to make sure they can handle that should not be necessary.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have over 5k reviews network wide, and I never ran across anything like this in review either. I see it reasonably often in the SD chatroom reporting spam, but thats something else I signed up for, so it doesn't phaze me either way. But I do think there is no need to subject people to this for no reason at all.