# Should this audit be removed?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just reviewed the following answer in the Low Quality Posts:

**Profanity below, please do not review if easily offended (Racism, Hate Speech etc.):**
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16332359

> FUCKING NIGGERS CUNT. WANT TO GET BASHED YOU STARVING ETHIOPIAN LOOKING MOTHERFUCKER. YOU STARVING PEASANTS CAN'T EVEN AFFORD FOOD YOU UGLY CUNTS. I BET YOUR DAD FUCKING HATES YOU AND YOU WERE MEANT TO BE AN ABORTION.
>
> Thanks for the help btw.

While I feel like it is helpful to review such things, in the real world I don't feel it is appropriate to expect everyone to do so in an audit, it's not often that such things are found on the network as in day to day usage they are removed extremely quickly.

But for the matter that 13 year olds and other vulnerable groups are legally allowed to participate on this website I don't believe that they should run the risk of being subject to these profanities as an audit. At least tone it down a little bit.

@Pekka웃 raises an interesting point in the comments, there are **far far worse** things that could appear in a review (which is totally obviously out of our control), but what happens in the event that something illicit *does* appear in a review? Would that be permanently deleted, beyond the point of even Mods being able to view? Would that appear as an audit?

**Update on this:**

Here's another Low Quality Post featuring [Proselytism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proselytism) (which RE: the above, *"[Proselytism] is illegal in some countries."*:

> proselytize(v) - *Convert or attempt to convert (someone) from one religion, belief, or opinion to another.* - OED

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16334642

> Why waste your time for all of these stuff when you can invest more time that MATTERS MOST! JESUS CHRIST. The way the truth and the life! Heaven is the only place where you don't have to work to survive, instead you'll have a Glorified body!!!!! Which never fades, which is the perfect ideal way of life. NO MORE PAIN NO MORE SUFFERING NO MORE TEARS. Please SANDY!! Turn to christ and REPENT!

Does it being illicit in certain countries mean that it shouldn't be an audit on SO?

Comment: Looks to me you are a bit of unworldly what 13 year olds are hearing at the schoolyards.

Comment: It could have been a real review. If people don't want to handle that type of content because they get easily offended by a bunch of pixels on the screen, they shouldn't do any reviews anyway..

Comment: @Nick Don't worry. I've got a 13 year old daughter. She behaves, but isn't easy to offend though, and that's good so.

Comment: Personally, I have no problem with seeing this content, but I can sort of see the OP's point. If something has been spam/offensive flagged to oblivion, does that action really need to be reviewed? Especially given that there could be *really* nasty stuff in here, the kind which even having on your computer might be illegal.

Comment: @Pekka웃 As a real review, no, as an audit, it's a great candidate.

Comment: @Servy only if clicking *Looks OK* on that audit lead to an instant life-long review ban without parole ...

Comment: Related [Don't use spam post as audits in the low quality review queue](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647)

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I had a longer answer about this here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333185/19679 , but for how offensive some of this stuff is (and it gets really bad, trust me), offensive-flagged content shouldn't be shown to reviewers. Spam works great as audits, because that stuff's pretty obvious and very rarely offensive in nature. Spam also hugely outnumbers offensive content, so removing the latter from audits wouldn't be removing all that many cases. As animuson says below, this may already be happening, but the system got confused by a spam flag that was validated on it.

Comment: @BradLarson I am going to say this yet again. Identifying spam requires following links, and reviewers should not have to follow links at all, let alone to pass an audit. This is the reason I gave up reviewing years ago.

Comment: @EJP - As a moderator, I haven't had to follow a link to identify spam in weeks, and I've deleted a ton of spam in that period. Almost all spam is obvious on its face due to glowing commercial language, wildly off-topic content, brand new users, and where the URL points. You don't need to follow links to know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44368611/19679), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44366281/19679), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44362193/19679) are spam. Someone approves them, that's a pretty good signal they aren't reviewing well.

Comment: @NickA your updated example is similar to the first - there was a spam flag on it when it was deleted (which marked the flag as helpful) which'll have made it a candidate for audit. That's been cleared so it'll no longer be in the audit pool.

Comment: I don't see the young teenager argument as a valid one myself. Most 13 year olds will be too busy playing Minecraft (gross generalisation on my part) to do reviewing on Stack Overflow; others that do are likely not mature enough to do it well enough that they can do it for very long before getting review banned. And those that are mature enough... well they don't need protecting. However: still agree that these should not be audits.

Answer (score 38):

The whole *purpose* of the review queues is to find really bad content and deal with it.  If you find content like this unacceptable to look at, ever, then you shouldn't be using the review queues.  The *design* of the review queues (or at least a number of them, including this one) is to actively find bad posts and show them to you, so that you can deal with them.  If that's not something that you're able to do, that's fine, it's not always an easy thing to deal with.  That an audit is showing you a bad post is very much *by design*, because the regular items in the queue will *also* often be full of really bad content.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the review audits are not supposed to select rude/offensive posts. Regardless of whether they might encounter it in the wild, it does *not* make sense at all to intentionally show someone a known offensive post even for auditing purposes. The problem here is the first flag on this post was actually a spam flag, which might be the one that the system is looking at in determining whether it was spam or offensive.

Comment: @animuson well, they actually do [Don't use spam post as audits in the low quality review queue](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647)

Comment: @Braiam I know spam flags trigger audits. But rude/offensive flags are not supposed to. I was saying this post got flagged as spam first, which might be why that check didn't get applied here.

Comment: @animuson I cleared the flags and applied a r/a flag to it - will that make it gone from audit?

Comment: @animuson according to Pops, spam and r/a flags are underwater [essentially the same flag](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35745740#35745740). Is the audit selection an exception to this rule?

Comment: "If you find content like this unacceptable to look at, ever, then you shouldn't be using the review queues." plus one for that. Made me smile :)

Comment: @Glorfindel I think the only exception. Which is one of the supporting reasons we continue to opt to keep them separate - there are occasionally slightly different things we'd like to do with the two flags, since they are very different content, even if they do mostly the same exact thing.

Comment: What would happen in the event that someone gets a malicious script through all of our sanitation? "Well you might run into it in the reviews, so we'll infect your computer" isn't a good defense. There is some content we as a community don't need to keep around and continue to distribute.

Comment: @krillgar If someone somehow finds some form of cross site scripting attack on SO then the solution is not to just delete the answer, but to fix the *major security hole in the site*.  There are also of course ways of hard deleting something, if that's really necessary.  Of course, deleted posts are still shown to 10k users, so just soft deleting such a post isn't fixing that problem anyway.

Answer (score 31):

I am going to voice in an answer what seems to be (from moderator comments) how things are supposed to work, with which I agree. In my opinion, **no, things like this should not be audits.**

The purposes of the queue and the audit system are related but not actually the same.  While the purpose of the *review queue* is indeed to find things like this and get rid of them as soon as possible, the purpose of *audits* is just to make sure reviewers are paying attention.

Hence, if something like this comes through as a real review, then the queue is doing its job. If something like this comes through as an *audit*, in some sense it is Stack Overflow that is deliberately showing it to you.  I see no good reason for deliberately subjecting people to stuff like this whether they get offended by it or not.

Comment: I think that this is a very important point, actually.

Comment: Absolutely this. I was going to say the same thing. Idiots putting it on here is one thing, but SO shouldn't "go out of their way" to keep that as "active content".

Answer (score 10):

#### Should you see offensive posts as audits?

No. As I've said before, it doesn't make sense for us to intentionally show you something that we already know was offensive and was flagged as such. **We do not create review audits from posts that were flagged as offensive** - that specific flag reason is not used anywhere in the selection criteria, which is one of the only things that sets it apart from spam flags.

#### So then why did you see this offensive post?

Well, because of the very simplistic way we select audits. While the queries for selecting these audits do *not* look for offensive posts, they *do* look for any post that has a helpful spam flag on it. The posts you mentioned in your question both had been flagged as spam by at least one person, and those flags got marked as helpful with the rest. Since they now had helpful spam flags and were still deleted, they were eligible - because while we don't look at offensive flags in selection, we don't explicitly *exclude* offensive flags either.

#### Is this a serious problem?

Well... maybe. Looking at the stats, there are a total of 3,060 posts in the entire Stack Overflow database that have *both* spam and offensive flags on them that are marked as helpful. However, 173 of those occurred just in the past 60 days, which are the ones eligible to be selected as review audits. If this becomes a more common occurrence of users utilizing the *completely wrong flag* for certain situations, we may need to add an extra check into the code to explicitly exclude posts with a helpful offensive flag. The graph below shows the number of posts that have at least one of both helpful spam flags and helpful offensive flags, grouped by the month the post was created.

[image: Graph of the problem]

Comment: 173 seems feasible enough for somebody to go through by hand if it would take time for an automatic process to be put in place (or if it werent to be done)

Comment: @NickA But that's an ever-changing number. You're talking about having to look at multiples of these *every day* to keep up, which is generally not a task I'd wish upon anyone. There's also not really anything we can do about it outside a dev manually changing the spam flag to declined or something. I wouldn't recommend moderators clearing the flags and re-flagging it as offensive, because that re-applies some of the penalties for an offensive post well after the post was created and already handled, which can mess with the system a bit. If it becomes a problem, we need to modify the query.