# What should be done about offensive posts flagged as spam?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, review-audits

Previously I've come along [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16332359), the content of which is clearly highly offensive.

And as stated in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350343/3270037):

> We do not create review audits from posts that were flagged as offensive

Part of the [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy is:

> **Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid ***vulgar terms*** and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.

This post isn't advertising anything, and yet was flagged as spam. Yet it does violate the be nice policy and wasn't flagged as rude or abusive.

It's previously been mentioned that a possibility would be to:

> add an extra check into the code to explicitly exclude posts with a helpful offensive flag. The graph below shows the number of posts that have at least one of both helpful spam flags and helpful offensive flags, grouped by the month the post was created.

Is there a reason why this cannot be implemented as content like this should never make it to audits?

Comment: Do you actually need to click that link to review that item?

Comment: @Servy not this one in particular no

Comment: Have you *ever* been in the situation where you needed to click on a spam link to review a post?  I know I haven't, and I've reviewed quite a lot of spam posts.

Comment: I think the warning would kind of defeat the purpose of the audit.  I always though that it was understood you may see bad content in the review queues.

Comment: @Servy admittedly, no, but there is always a chance

Comment: @NathanOliver Presumably the warning would be before even entering the queue that some number of items will be NSFW, not on an individual item.

Comment: @NathanOliver arguably the link in this post should've been marked as offensive rather than spam, and according to animuson's [answer to an older post of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350343/3270037)  offensive posts should **not** be in audits.

Comment: i mean... who would be the person that indicates that it is NSFW for such a feature to work?

Comment: @rene perhaps not, but that's not what I'm asking about, I'm asking about all NSFW content

Comment: @KevinB The feature would just be a warning that everyone always see before entering the queue, so no person would need to indicate anything.

Comment: Yeah... that post got 5 spam flags and 1 rude...

Comment: If we had sufficient AI to detect when a post's content was NSFW, we wouldn't need the review queues at all. We'd just block that content from coming in in the first place. I'm not really sure what you're proposing here.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not asking for detection of individual posts, but a warning prior to entering the queue

Comment: Oh…um, I think everyone already knows you're going to be reviewing garbage, so a warning seems superfluous, but sure, why not?

Comment: @NickA So now we're to a point where we're worrying about something that no one has ever actually seen even a single instance of it happening, and to prevent this mythical situation you're suggesting that we inform people that in the queue where they're going to spend their time looking for spam to remove they might end up coming across some spam.  This all seems rather unnecessary...

Comment: @CodyGray The main reason why not is you're just wasting people's time...

Comment: @Servy I don't know... might get more people interested in reviewing if we tempt them with "fr33 pr0n links" may be found! :p

Comment: @Servy No, I'm saying there should be a warning for posts like the above and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16332359) as offensive posts can slip through the net. I'm not even suggesting that a warning appears every time you enter the queue but at least the first time. As it stands there is no indication of the sort of content that may be seen in review, and for those that have only seen the good side of SO it may come as a surprise, and hence forth put them off review if easily offended

Comment: @NickA The *goal* of the queue is for people to find bad content and indicate that it's bad.   You're *going* to see spam and offensive content if you review items in the queue.  Your *primary* goal in most of the queues (including that one) is to identify spam and offensive posts so that others *don't* need to deal with it.  That you're going to come across offensive posts is part of the job description.  If someone is surprised to see spam in the queue then *they shouldn't even be in the queue in the first place*.

Comment: @Servy The job description is "[Evaluating new posts, Voting to close or reopen questions and Reviewing suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review)". In no way does it say that there could be content people may find offensive

Comment: @NickA It says that you're evaluating posts.  You're evaluating them because they might be problematic, among the particularly problematic types of posts are spam or offensive content.  Additionally if you look at the full description of the Triage queue it mentions, among other things, identifying spam.

Comment: @Servy and yet it doesn't say it in the SE queue where spam can be introduced, and even if not the case of adding a warning, this shouldn't have been an audit as it falls under "A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)"

Comment: @NickA And even if SO was 100% perfect at keeping content that you find offensive out of audits, the whole point of the queue itself is to specifically identify bad content in *actual* posts.  You're going to see plenty of *non-audit* posts that are spam or offensive, that will require you to mark them as such.  If you're unwilling to sift through posts trying to identify good and bad content, but it's unacceptable to you to come across bad content, then *don't volunteer to sift through content and find the bad stuff*.  The people doing it realize that they will occasionally see bad content.

Comment: @Servy alright, I've steered the question differently

Comment: The post *is* spam.  It meets the criteria for it in every respect.

Comment: @Servy perhaps, but I'd say that the rude or offensive flag takes precedence if it is also appropriate

Comment: Regarding the new title, I think spam was a perfectly valid flag for the question in question. It contained a spammy link to an external site. Now, it just so happens that it was a spammy link to NSFW content, but that just means it fits *both* "spam" and "rude/abusive" criteria. And castigating people for not properly imposing a salience ranking on these two flags is absurd. The important thing is to get garbage flagged with a reasonably accurate flag so it can be removed. The *real* problem here is that we are now dissecting that garbage, months later. I'm straining to see why.

Comment: @CodyGray because spam flags don't necessarily remove the garbage, they can make them audits. Offensive flags will always remove the content, and offensive content should not be in audits

Comment: @CodyGray updated title and question again

Comment: @NickA: That doesn't mean that the action taken was *wrong*.  Additionally I think it makes for one of the best audits out there; if you somehow think that a link to a porn site (and you really don't have to click it) makes for an on-topic question, you have no right to review *anything*.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not saying it is wrong, it is an appropriate flag, I'm asking what's worse, spam or abusive content?

Comment: @NickA:  Yes.  Pick one.  It will make its way into the incinerator.

Comment: @Makoto There, I've removed all reference to spam from the question

Comment: Ugh. Chameleon questions are just as bad on Meta as they are on the main site. If you want to totally change your question after you've posted it and attracted discussion, then you should probably post a new question. Also, with the new focus, it's unclear to me how this is materially different from your *last* discussion on the same topic, using the same example.

Comment: @CodyGray because this is a feature request, the last was a discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You changed the example you linked to here, so now the comments don't make sense.

The fix for your *new* example is probably to exclude anything flagged as "rude or abusive" from audits. [As of December 14, 2018, this is done.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362493/nsfw-triage-review-audit/377864#377864)

The fix for your *old* example... Is nothing. That's exactly the sort of spam that regularly gets posted and the purpose of audits is to train folks to recognize it (*without* following the links) and delete it so that no one has to risk their job or mental wellbeing.

Comment: `The fix for your new example is probably to exclude anything flagged as "rude or abusive" from audits.` My understanding is that already happens.  For the specific example shown, the post was *not* an audit, and it was shown *before* it was deleted as offensive.  It going into the review queue helped it get more delete votes/flags quicker than if it wouldn't have, so that all looks good.

Comment: The audit *currently* linked to from the question here dates to back in June, and was deleted by a combination of (one) spam and several offensive flags a few days earlier, @Servy. The link itself goes to the audit, not any other review task; there is no review queue for spam or offensive posts. The post was briefly in the First Posts queue, but was deleted before being reviewed.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that it was deleted before the audit, then undeleted, then re-deleted, I just saw the deletion date as being after the audit review date.

Comment: Yeah, Nick's re-using an example from [a previous meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350236/should-this-audit-be-removed) @Servy (after being roundly criticized for his original example). Back in June, a moderator undeleted and re-flagged the current example in order to make it ineligible for use as an audit.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, the example used here is in reference to the previous meta post, also posted by me. The potential improvement to the system suggested by animuson in their answer to that post is now the subject of this feature request, I've retracted my previous statements on the spam post as ultimately, the post was also spam and hence the flag was valid.

Comment: @Shog9 Does spam really live long enough these days to go into review queues? I've never actually seen spam in review queues, afaik. Only in smokey reports. Is it still necessary to hit reviewers in the face with spam audits in this time and age?

Comment: First Posts, Late Answers and Triage often feature spam, @Magisch - posts can end up in those queues before anyone else sees them. Low Quality is less likely (especially on Stack Overflow), but still possible.