# Azure ad causing excessive warnings

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, advertising

This seemed strange enough that I felt obliged to point it out.

The ad for Microsoft Azure (primary source of warnings: https://cdn.adsafeprotected.com/sca.17.1.10.js) caused 5 warnings and also used console.log, both actions that it should not be doing.

[image]

[image]

Here is a full dump of the iframe it loaded: http://pastebin.com/AavEwTmy

In addition, it loaded nearly 70,000 characters of additional scripts

[image]

This seems excessive and overly invasive.

Comment: Hmm... I'm definitely gonna need more information to determine what ads are responsible for this. More fun is that we're about to change to a new month, so the ad in question may expire shortly once we pass over to 1 March. Any chance you can provide any additional insights? Tags? Advertisers (a big ask, I know)?

Comment: @stevvve - The ad is for Microsoft Azure. `<iframe id="ados_frame_adzerk950902514_2720600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="250" width="300" data-integralas-id-eb525cdf-611e-fc0d-78a6-12d318fe4ef0=""></iframe>`

Comment: @stevvve - Here is a dump of the iframe's html http://pastebin.com/AavEwTmy

Comment: Wow, that's excellent. Thank you, @Travis J! We'll dig in.

Comment: not the first time of [Microsoft ads causing trouble](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289255/839601)

Comment: Not even the first time [I have had it happen to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196102/178816) apparently.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335956/792066

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386487/1541563

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So... I have some bad news.

Jean from our Ad Sales team and Haney our engineering manager have been going back and forth with various folks from IAS (the company that actually runs these ads) for most of the past two weeks. We've tried as much as humanly possible to communicate the issues with this script and even provided information on how to fix them.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that they're going to be fixed.  The latest information we have on this is that these errors are in some fashion intentional, triggered as part of a probe the script runs to detect fraud.

The sad state of affairs is that advertisers and unscrupulous clients are locked in an arms race, with the rest of us caught in the crossfire. I recommend judicious use of software such as uBlock Origin to mitigate the damage until this campaign has ended.

I sincerely apologize for the disruption.

Comment: NoScripts can convert all the warnings in a single error, in case you don't want to block all ads.