# Fist Bumps and Teams: What's going on with this ad?

Tags: discussion, advertising, stack-overflow-for-teams

I just saw this ad on Stack Overflow:

[image: FIST + BUMP ad]

This is a really confusing ad. It doesn't clearly communicate what product it's advertising. The word "teams" is in there, but it's not clear that the ad is advertising a separate Stack Overflow for Teams product, rather than claiming that regular Stack Overflow is private and secure.

Heck, at first, I thought there was some new Stack Overflow competitor called "FISTBUMP" or "FIST + BUMP". What the heck do the bumping fists have to do with any Stack Overflow product or branding? Why "FIST" and "BUMP" and the giant plus sign? Are we rebranding upvotes as fistbumps? Where did the entire lower half of this ad come from?

Comment: `fistbump.qa` seems to be available, or at least it doesn't currently resolve to anything.

Comment: Reminds me of this https://i.stack.imgur.com/nes2c.jpg

Comment: @BhargavRao did you mean "private questions for teams & secure answers of any size - Fist Bump"?

Comment: StackOverflow Fight Club - launching in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @Turnip HEY! The first rule of Fight Club is "You do not talk about Fight Club.".

Comment: Maybe it's a campaign to make sure that new users no longer expect a welcoming place.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, Bhargav's link is to a work safe image.

Comment: Seriously, why is there a big + sign between the fists?

Comment: I like how it was necessary to write "FIST   BUMP" under the fists, in an attempt to make the image understandable.

Comment: @Lundin The ad was written in PHP. It converts the fist bumps to integers before adding them

Comment: Looks like the ad designing neural network needs a bit more training.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, are you suggesting there are some NSFW images out there that involve fisting?

Comment: The resemblence of this logo to a certain other image which is completely inappropriate for a work environment is unfortunate.

Comment: related: [Anyone else annoyed by this advertisement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289255/839601) :)

Comment: @yivi Presumably it was added because, without "fist bump" written underneath, the imagery looks rather violent. I'm led to believe that punching your coworkers until they provide you with the information you need - while occasionally tempting - is not considered a best practice for knowledge sharing in most organisations.

Comment: If the concept of "sock-puppetric" serial-upvoting needed a symbol, this would be it.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland If AndrewGrimm is thinking the same thing I'm thinking, this image evokes a certain infamous sexually graphic photo with the word "goat" in it.

Comment: @KodosJohnson yes, one which once had a TLD from Christmas Island.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. It's *obviously* saying "PRIVATE QUESTIONS FIST, SECURE ANSWERS BUMP".

Comment: It's advertising a safe place for people to ask questions before engaging in fisting, no matter how large the fist. I for one would want more than a couple of questions answered before trying it.

Comment: https://fistbump.stackexchange.com/ duh

Comment: A fist bump? A pound? A terrorist fist jab?

Comment: It's so obvious! It's an ad for https://secure.php.net/ the secure+not+by+default way to browse PHP's docs+Q&A+news because that plus sign is PHP purple. Their Q&A is the reason Stackoverflow wasn't invented 20 years ago, and yet probably the reason it was. Here's the proof:

`echo ""+"private"+"secure"+"questions"+"answers"+"team"+"" == "PHP";`

It's so obvious now that I think about it.

Comment: Did you see the "Watch tags" add? It looks like two robots with orange feet (antigrav units?) are fistbumping. And their fists almost look like a plus sign...

Answer (score 93):

Thanks for your feedback. Elaine here on the marketing team at Stack Overflow.

I agree with you that this ad is confusing on all the points you mentioned.

The fistbump and plus sign were meant to convey a sense of collaboration and team spirit, but it's clear that the copy and icons are mismatched, making the overall message confusing.

We are working on refreshing our Stack Overflow for Teams ads, so you should see a change pretty soon. Thanks for bringing this one to our attention!

Comment: Good answer! *fistbump*

Comment: Also I would recommend stylistically to show fist bumps in the future with the palm facing down (fingers underneath) rather than the palm facing out. This might be a more recognizable image of a "nice one!" fist bump.

Comment: @TylerH flat palm is very unhygienic and probably old fashioned and cartoony too.

Comment: @barlop flat palm? Are you thinking of a high five? That is something different from a fist bump.

Comment: @TylerH oh I see what you mean.. I thought when you said palm facing down you meant open hand like a group handshake.   But yeah I agree a fist bump with palm facing down is normal.

Comment: Also, seems to me "high five" and "fist bumps" are a pretty US-centered cultural reference, even from a EU "westerner" point of view like mine.

Comment: @Pac0 I think, “high five” is quiet popular in the EU. Fist bumb, not so… especially not in the way presented in the ad. 1) not under this name 2) with fists rotated 90°, i.e. … My first association when seeing the ad was, besides fighting, two angry guys hammering on the table. Well, could be a team, complaining about their stupid boss…

Comment: agree about orientation... and actually I thought the were fighting either over an hospital or Switzerland ;)

Comment: This looks like some sort of drug deal going down to me.

Comment: @Machavity What is this *fistbump* you speak of? Did you mean *fist + bump*?

Comment: If only there was a site that dealt with [design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) or [user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @Machavity: When the comment receives 1.5 times more fistbumps than the A.