# “Report this ad” does not rotate ads (Or: Can we have ads that don't have faces staring back at us?)

Tags: discussion, bug, feature-request, advertising

Lately, I've been seeing this ad for Azure (...even though I'm already an Azure customer):

> [image]

It's unsettling when faces on my screen stare right back at me.

So I clicked the “Report this ad” link and dutifully filled-out the form, expecting the ad to be cycled out and replaced with one less likely to feel like I’m being watched… but no, the ad still shows.

---

I'll admit I'm on-the-spectrum and a common trait of [ASD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_spectrum) is finding it [*very uncomfortable* to look at faces](https://www.sciencealert.com/for-those-with-autism-eye-contact-isn-t-just-weird-it-s-distressing), especially those looking back at us. I assume Stack Overflow is interested in advancing [neurodiversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurodiversity), so in the spirit of that (and given my impression of the rest of SO's user-base...) can SO's ad-moderators request that ads posted *don't* feature faces staring at the user?

...or an "I don't like this ad" button that rotates out a different ad?

- <sub>INB4: "just tighten your adblock settings"</sub>
- <sub>Yes, I clicked the "Report this ad" link too</sub>

Comment: Just tighten your adblock settings :-P

Comment: Microsoft ads are troublesome [as usual](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289255/839601)

Comment: Ads just can't stick to facts, but have to get you in with fake smiling faces by models. I can't stand fake or lies, so I'm glad ad blockers exist.

Comment: some user also have such pictures in their profile... (bit smaller)

Comment: Doesn't "Report this ad" hide the ad for you, cycling in some other ad? I've never tried it on the sidebar ads, but I have some vague recollection that it worked on the banner ads (which are displayed on sites where you haven't yet earned the "reduced ads" privilege).

Comment: The solution _is_ Adblock though. Unless these job adverts are otherwise of interest to you, then it's no loss.

Comment: and then there's me who can't stand seeing a picture of human in SO at all.

Comment: To pile on Lundin, it's also the only solution if you want to use the modern internet [without constantly wanting to facedesk whenever you visit a website](https://twitter.com/karpathy/status/1435827240286109702). Seriously, install an ad blocker - it's a lot faster than waiting for the ad mods to maybe do something, and assumes they're actually willing to, and technically can. (I'm not sure what tools they have, or if they're capable of that level of control.)

Comment: I think the solution *is* for you to take matters into your own hands here (e.g. an ad-blocking tool or user script that lets you block specific images). You can apparently also report the ad, which should prevent it from appearing for you anymore, but the ad won't be taken out of circulation for anyone else unless it has inappropriate content (which is not the case here). Alternatively, just refresh the page you are on to load a different ad.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you will accept as a solution since you suggest a "don't show me this ad" option but that's exactly the outcome of the "report this ad" link you said you already clicked.

Comment: @gnat That doesn't seem like an issue with Microsoft, but rather someone whose thoughts are in the gutter.

Comment: @TylerH I imagine they want a "Don't show me any ad with staring faces" option, without having to report each one individually.

Comment: If you haven't gotten an ad-blocker yet, maybe now would be a good time to do so? Ad-blockers take care of _all_ ads, including ones with faces.

Comment: To pile on @Zoe, you can get DNS based ad-blockers such as [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) or [NextDNS](https://nextdns.io) that won't even take any of your CPU or make you install browser extensions. They can be configured to work network wide.

Comment: I use the [AdBlocker Ultimate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblocker-ultimate/ohahllgiabjaoigichmmfljhkcfikeof?hl=en) extension. Buh-bye, nonsense vying for my attention. Buh-bye malicious clickbait. Hello, using the internet for my intended purpose.

Comment: @CodyGray No, the old ad-system _did_ have the “AdChoices” link which did work, but this ad doesn’t, and I did click the “Report this ad” link and fill-out the form but it didn’t remove the ad.

Comment: @Zoe I have an adblocker (uBlock Origin) but I don’t have any custom rules set-up for SO’s self-hosted ads, but I do have my SO account’s “reduced ads” option enabled. I didn’t want to completely block SO’s ads because so-far SO’s ads have been unobtrusive and even sometimes useful/informative - and also probably my Catholic-guilt has something to do with it too.

Comment: Wait.. a 117k-rep user sees ads?

Comment: Yes, if you don't have an adblock

Comment: Re "finding it _very uncomfortable_ to look at faces", I can relate. I still recall being completely turned off by computer books published by Wrox for a while back in the 2000s, simply because they prominently showed the faces of the authors on the covers of almost all of their computing books. It seemed a bizarre thing to do at the time, and it still does.

Comment: I think this post is a bit ironic considering it itself shows the face looking at you to everybody that reads it. While the option to cycle the ad makes sense in general, attempting to just remove the specific ad, or have Microsoft change the ad, because you are in an infinitesimally small minority which feels uncomfortable to them is just silly, IMHO. Society should not conform to the exception of the exception.

Comment: @julealgon [1] There's no irony, and no need to be disingenuous about the OP including the photo. You surely realize that the image is central to the post, and there would be (justifiable) complaints if it wasn't shown. [2] Slightly OT, but while you may be right that there are an "infinitesimally small minority" of viewers who feel _uncomfortable_ about the image, I'm pretty sure there are a lot more who feel annoyed by the use of mug shots in ads on SO, because we are hardwired to notice them, and be distracted by them. That face the OP doesn't need to be attractive to get your attention.

Comment: It's also reasonable for OP to think that SO would be interested in feedback from someone who's not only looking at but actually clicking on the ads.

Comment: At first I was thinking, "Ughh not another complaining post", but then I realized that yes, it's quite confrontational. _can SO's ad-moderators request that ads posted don't feature faces staring at the user?_ ---> There's no way to filter that, I like your second suggestion more. But even then, how do you detect if an ad is posted twice if the ID is different?

Comment: @CaiusJard In the sidebar, yes. The [reduced ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) only removes banner ads

Comment: @10rep in this day and age of free facial recognition APIs you'd imagine it'd be pretty easy to block ads that contain faces..

Comment: Actually I'm on no doubt Dai has the prowess to build an app that scans their own screen for faces and paints and always on top rectangle over them.. :D

Comment: (But at the very least perhaps very high rep users shouldn't see ads at all)

Comment: @CaiusJard Memories of _eigenfaces_ in my computer-vision classes...

Comment: As another user already pointed out. You could face (no pun intended) a similar issue with user profiles. In a Q/A you could have dozens of people "starring" at you. Or does the small picture size somehow makes it easier? Do you think SO should have similar guidelines for user profiles ?

Comment: @customcommander User avatars on SO are **tiny** in comparison to the size of the face in that ad, and I've only ever seen a handful of actual human faces used as avatars, and when they do they don't tend to stare directly at the camera.

Comment: This may feel annoying but still. Just ignore them. The ads are very small, so they can't distract you when you're doing your normal business. If it's unsettling, don't look at it. Focus on the questions. What do you do in real life? Do you try remove people who look at you from existence or do you try to not look at them?

Comment: @skomisa "I'm pretty sure there are a lot more who feel annoyed by the use of mug shots in ads on SO, because we are hardwired to notice them, and be distracted by them. That face the OP doesn't need to be attractive to get your attention.", which is exactly why it is used, right? It works, they precisely want to attract your attention in an ad. Trying to "disallow" that in any way is basically a form of censorship. As I mentioned, I'm fine with having some form of option to rotate an ad, but that's where it should stop. Any attempt to special case for "faces" etc is a no-no.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam IRL at the very least one can turn away from the faces staring at them. If they are *literally* next to the content you read, that's not really possible.

Comment: I think regardless of condition, the ad is designed to be slightly creepy and thus distracting on purpose. Good ads should be about conveying information about available products and services to potential customers (ie: people who might actually _want_ them), not about being as annoying as possible to pull attention away from the content and towards the ad.

Comment: My thanks to @SteveBennett for putting the picture of the ad behind the spoiler effect. I block ads via Pi Hole, not an ad blocker in the browser, so I don't see the ads normally, and seeing that dude staring at me when people update the question was weirding me out. Anyway, back to the bickering :)

Comment: @CaiusJard: As someone who uses an image processing display manager, I can say with confidence, no he can't nor can anybody else. I'm having to put up with 2FPS for an O(4) operation in CPU (four passes over the image pixel by pixel, two of which are the blit operations required).

Comment: @DaveCousineau "Good ads should be about conveying information..." I've been saying this for decades and got various combinations of choices from the "ad excuse" bingo card, here's an excerpt: ["ads are meant to train people to want stuff", "no actually the ad is working but you are too stupid to realize it", "the ad didn't work therefore you aren't the target audience", "what do I care if they work, companies pay for ads", "that ad is just there to tell people Microsoft exists", "you aren't the target audience because you don't like to spend money", ...]

Comment: ... I don't really feel bad about having super strict adblocking. The ad industry is high off their own fumes at this point, recycling each others' flimsy sales pitches. I'm not their target audience, I think before spending money (including company money); I'm probably doing them a favor by opting myself out. I look at that ad and immediately think "OK 'free trial', what's the catch"; I already lost interest because they're not upfront about it. It's obviously not free forever. I want to know how they're making money to make sure it's going to be mutually beneficial.

Comment: I can recommand AdBlock Plus - I'm using it for years and never saw a single ad on SE.

Comment: This remains an issue. In addition, the "report ads" dialog is very user-unfriendly. You shouldn't have to attach the ad image; it should already know which ad you're reporting. This goes double since attempting to save the image only gets you the white background with the Azure logo. I will now install an ad blocker because SO failed to address this in a timely manner.

Answer (score 25):

Bletch. Without regard to the particular reason why, "Report this ad" should always not show that ad to that user again. You now know that person detests it.

Comment: Do we limit how many ads a user could report in this way, in a given time period? there's only so many ads in the rotation, afterall (not that it matters at all to me, given that i don't see ads at all, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯)

Comment: @KevinB: No point limiting the number they could report. If you posted 50 ads and got 50 ads from a user saying "I hate it." your add campaign was a remarkable success. I'm assuming the number of offensive reports are sent back to the people who buy ad placements. That report is worth more to the advertiser than an impression, and furthermore future impressions for the same user are worth nothing.

Comment: @KevinB If you limit it, they will install an adblocker, and you lose out alltogether.

Comment: I would consider that to be a success @Tschallacka

Comment: Put another way, someone just blanket reporting everything is someone not providing useful reports. If a user doesn't want to see any of the ads, or sees most of the ads being presented as being problematic, clearly that's someone who should install an adblocker. For more legitimate reports, such as the one in question, a limit of 2-3 would never even be reached and therefore not cause issue.

Comment: @KevinB: I suspect OP will quite easily hit 2 ads per day to report, not 2-3 total.